# Change component view location in Asp.Net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On ASP.NET 5 a Component view must be in one of two places:

```
Views/NameOfControllerUsingComponent/Components/ComponentName/Default.cshtml
Views/Shared/Components/ComponentName/Default.cshtml
```

Is there a way to change this to:

```
Views/NameOfControllerUsingComponent/Components/ComponentName.cshtml
Views/Shared/Components/ComponentName.cshtml
```

So basically, remove the folder ComponentName and change the view name from Default.cshtml to ComponentName.cshtml.

For me it makes more sense ... Is it possible?

Comment: You are able to change the view name by explicitly calling the view you want to show. This allows you to use multiple views in one ViewComponent. This means this structure defines where to find the views. IMO with this in mind it doesn't make sense to use the component name as the default view.

Comment: Yes, but it will look for it in ComponentName folder. But yes, I didn't think of a case where a ViewComponent might have many views ... Do you think that is very common? I see a ViewCoponent more like a controller action and having only one view. But, yes, if a component can use many views then the default structure makes sense.

Comment: But it is still implemented with the possibility to have many views. Anyway, I see you problem with that :) Maybe it makes sense to create an new proposal on Github: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues

Answer (score 7):

That convention is only applied if you create a view component that derives from the base [`ViewComponent`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/34d4dfdef8a6555c8ce841263893823891a0aeed/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewComponent.cs) provided by the framework.

That class defines the `View` helpers, which return a [`ViewViewComponentResult`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/eef6c3883a7e27b8387b0925f0b6a88df0a484c5/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewComponents/ViewViewComponentResult.cs):

```
public ViewViewComponentResult View<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model)
{
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(ViewData, model);
    return new ViewViewComponentResult
    {
        ViewEngine = ViewEngine,
        ViewName = viewName,
        ViewData = viewData
    };
}
```

The `ViewViewComponentResult` is where the conventions are defined:

```
private const string ViewPathFormat = "Components/{0}/{1}";
private const string DefaultViewName = "Default";

public async Task ExecuteAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
{
    ...

    string qualifiedViewName;
    if (!isNullOrEmptyViewName &&
        (ViewName[0] == '~' || ViewName[0] == '/'))
    {
        // View name that was passed in is already a rooted path, the view engine will handle this.
        qualifiedViewName = ViewName;
    }
    else
    {
        // This will produce a string like:
        //
        //  Components/Cart/Default
        //
        // The view engine will combine this with other path info to search paths like:
        //
        //  Views/Shared/Components/Cart/Default.cshtml
        //  Views/Home/Components/Cart/Default.cshtml
        //  Areas/Blog/Views/Shared/Components/Cart/Default.cshtml
        //
        // This supports a controller or area providing an override for component views.
        var viewName = isNullOrEmptyViewName ? DefaultViewName : ViewName;

        qualifiedViewName = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            ViewPathFormat,
            context.ViewComponentDescriptor.ShortName,
            viewName);
    }

    ...

}
```

> Notice that if you return from your view component the full path to a view as the view name, then the view component will use the specified view.
>   Something like:
>
> ```
> return View("~/Views/Shared/Components/ComponentName.cshtml")
> ```

Since there is no way to modify the conventions in `ViewViewComponentResult` and your approach would only work for view components with a single view, you could build something using the root view paths approach:

- Create your own `ViewComponent` class extending the existing one.
- Add new helper methods or *hide* the existing `View` methods to return a view using a full path:

  ```
  public ViewViewComponentResult MyView<TModel>(TModel model)
  {
      var viewName = string.Format(
              "~/Views/Shared/Components/{0}.cshtml", 
              this.ViewComponentContext.ViewComponentDescriptor.ShortName)
      return View(viewName, model);
  }
  ```
- If you add new methods you might be able to add them as extension methods of `ViewComponent` instead of having to create your own class.

Another alternative would be creating a class `SingleViewViewComponent` copying the code for [`ViewComponent`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/34d4dfdef8a6555c8ce841263893823891a0aeed/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewComponent.cs) but replacing the implementation of `ViewViewComponentResult View<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model)`. Then when creating your view components, you would inherit from `SingleViewViewComponent` instead of `ViewComponent`.

Comment: I just created an issue on MVC's Gihub ... IMHO the system could look in Views/NameOfControllerUsingComponent/Components/ComponentName.cshtml and also in Views/NameOfControllerUsingComponent/Components/ComponentName.cshtml ... These way both approaches would work.

Comment: @MiguelMoura, can you please link to the issue you created?

Comment: Thanks, a nice clean clear answer. I didn't much fancy going down the expander route and hacking about with the default functionality works it's just more code I really don't want to have to maintain :)

Answer (score 3):

Took me a weekend to finally find a way around this that didn't involve writing a custom ViewComponentResult.

in MVC .Net Core, you can add your own `IViewLocationExpander` to the RazorViewEngineOptions in your startup.cs's ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CustomLocationExpander());
        });

    }
```

This allows you to add custom Paths that are used in conjuction with the `ViewLocationExpanderContext` ViewName ({0}), ControllerName ({1}).

The main issue is that you can't *alter* the context's values, which makes it seemingly impossible to change the default View Component's ViewName of `Component/ComponentName/Default`

**Seemingly impossible**

Here's the trick, the ExpandViewLocations is called with each View(), each time it doesn't have a fully qualified view path.  Which means you can add custom logic.  What I did was add a catch to detect ViewComponents in the `PopulateValues` method, then added to the `context.Values` dictionary, and then if that dictionary has those custom values, it will prepend to the Paths the list of paths that use *my generated view name* instead of the context.

It's fully reverse compatible, and shouldn't impact performance one bit.

```
public class CustomLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    private const string _CustomViewPath = "CustomViewPath";
    private const string _CustomController = "CustomController";
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        Regex DefaultComponentDetector = new Regex(@"^((?:[Cc]omponents))+\/+([\w\.]+)\/+(.*)");

        
        /*
         * If successful, 
         * Group 0 = FullMatch (ex "Components/MyComponent/Default")
         * Group 1 = Components (ex "Component")
         * Group 2 = Component Name (ex "MyComponent")
         * Group 3 = View Name (ex "Default")
         * */
        var DefaultComponentMatch = DefaultComponentDetector.Match(context.ViewName);

        if (DefaultComponentMatch.Success)
        {
            // Will render Components/ComponentName as the new view name
            context.Values.Add(_CustomViewPath, string.Format("{0}/{1}", DefaultComponentMatch.Groups[1].Value, DefaultComponentMatch.Groups[2].Value));
            context.Values.Add(_CustomController, context.ControllerName);
        }

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        /* Parameters:
         * {2} - Area Name
         * {1} - Controller Name
         * {0} - View Name
         * */
        List<string> Paths = new List<string> { 
            // Default View Locations to support imported / legacy paths
            "/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

            // Adds Feature Folder Rendering
            "/Features/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml",

            // Handles My Custom rendered views
            "/{0}.cshtml"
            };

        // Add "Hard Coded" custom view paths to checks, along with the normal default view paths for backward compatibility
        if (context.Values.ContainsKey(_CustomViewPath))
        {
            // Generate full View Paths with my custom View Name and Controller Name

            var CombinedPaths = new List<string>(Paths.Select(x => string.Format(x, context.Values[_CustomViewPath], context.Values[_CustomController], "")));
            // Add in original paths for backward compatibility
            CombinedPaths.AddRange(Paths);

            return CombinedPaths;
        }
        
        // Returns the normal view paths
        return Paths;
    }
}
```