# ASP.NET View Components: Remove default path to view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to return a View with a specific path to the view like so, `return View(~/Views/Home)`. The type to be returned is an `IViewComponentResult`.

However, when the site gets rendered, it tries to find the view under: `Components/{controller-name}/~/Views/Home`.

So I want to ask you guys, if you know a smart way to delete `Components/{controller-name}/` from the path. My view component class is deriving from the `ViewComponent` class.

The problem regarding this is that right now, you have to have a "Components" folder with the name of the controller as a subfolder which contains a Default.cshtml file. I do not like to have all my components inside one folder. I hope you have a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convention happened in `ViewViewComponentResult` hence if you don't want the convention, you will have to implement your own `IViewComponentResult`

since mvc is open source, you could copy all the `ViewViewComponentResult` and then change the convention bit.

so essentially two things has to be done:

1. create your own `IViewComponentResult` - lets call it `MyViewViewComponentResult`
2. create a helper in your implemented `ViewComponent` to replace the original `View()` - purpose is to returns the custom `MyViewViewComponentResult` you created at step 1

### create your own `IViewComponentResult`

the convention happened at ExecuteAsync:

```
public class ViewViewComponentResult : IViewComponentResult
{
    // {0} is the component name, {1} is the view name.
    private const string ViewPathFormat = "Components/{0}/{1}";
    private const string DefaultViewName = "Default";

    ....

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(ViewComponentContext context)
    {
        ....
        if (result == null || !result.Success)
        {
            // This will produce a string like:
            //
            //  Components/Cart/Default
            //
            // The view engine will combine this with other path info to search paths like:
            //
            //  Views/Shared/Components/Cart/Default.cshtml
            //  Views/Home/Components/Cart/Default.cshtml
            //  Areas/Blog/Views/Shared/Components/Cart/Default.cshtml
            //
            // This supports a controller or area providing an override for component views.
            var viewName = isNullOrEmptyViewName ? DefaultViewName : ViewName;
            var qualifiedViewName = string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                ViewPathFormat,
                context.ViewComponentDescriptor.ShortName,
                viewName);

            result = viewEngine.FindView(viewContext, qualifiedViewName, isMainPage: false);
        }

        ....
    }

    .....
}
```

so change it to your need

### create a helper in your implemented `ViewComponent` which replace the original `View`

so base on original

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a result which will render the partial view with name <paramref name="viewName"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="viewName">The name of the partial view to render.</param>
/// <param name="model">The model object for the view.</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="ViewViewComponentResult"/>.</returns>
public ViewViewComponentResult View<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model)
{
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(ViewData, model);
    return new ViewViewComponentResult
    {
        ViewEngine = ViewEngine,
        ViewName = viewName,
        ViewData = viewData
    };
}
```

you would do something like

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a result which will render the partial view with name <paramref name="viewName"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="viewName">The name of the partial view to render.</param>
/// <param name="model">The model object for the view.</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="ViewViewComponentResult"/>.</returns>
public MyViewViewComponentResult MyView<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model)
{
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(ViewData, model);
    return new MyViewViewComponentResult
    {
        ViewEngine = ViewEngine,
        ViewName = viewName,
        ViewData = viewData
    };
}
```

so in future you would call `MyView()` instead of `View()`

more info check out another SO: [Change component view location in Asp.Net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527801/change-component-view-location-in-asp-net-5)