# grouping asp.net core components folder

Tags: asp.net-core, directory, components, view-components

I want to group components folder. But I can't group it because it looks for the folder name I named just below the components folder. I want to group like in the photos below:

[image]

[image]

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("odemeSecenekleri")
```

but it is looking for "odemeSecenekleri" folder under components folder. I want " components > footer > odemeSecenekleri ".  components > odemeSecenekleri not. I want to group components according to their pages.

[image]

[image]

I want to make a folders like in the photo above. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is really the .cshtml files which you have to be concerned about. Asp.Net Core does not care where you put the rest of the ViewComponent files.

To modify how your project searches for Views, you need to create a custom class which the implements IViewLocationExpander interface and configure it in Startup.cs

This link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65983829/13550447

From what it appears you are trying to do, you may also want to consider creating Feature folders.
There are many examples if you search for Feature Folders in Asp.Net Core.

Here is one example: https://scottsauber.com/2016/04/25/feature-folder-structure-in-asp-net-core/